# Execute js on page load as well as click event

Tags: jquery

Im listening for a click event with the following:

```
$('div').bind("click"),function() {
   // do something
});
```

Its working except I need the event to also fire on page load. How can I make it do this?

Comment: side note: `.bind()` is deprecated, use `.on()`, assuming u are using jQuery version 1.8+

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Trigger the click:

```
$('div').bind("click"),function() {
    // do something
}).click();
```

Answer (score 3):

```
$(document).ready(function() {
   $('div').on("click", doSomething);
   doSomething();
});

function doSomething() {
  //do the load and click thing
}
```